# Sinatra - Setting Cache-Control Headers via config.ru

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, rack, jekyll

I'm currently running an Octopress (based on Jekyll) site on Heroku's Cedar stack—the code lives here: https://github.com/elithrar/octopress

I want to selectively apply a `Cache-Control` header based on the file type:

- `.html` files get a value of `public, max-age=3600`
- `.css|.js|.png|.ico` (etc) get a value of `public, max-age=604800` - alternatively, I'd like to apply this rule to anything served from the `/stylesheets', '/javascripts', '/imgs'` directories.

Have used both `set :static_cache_control , [:public, :max_age => 3600]` and just the vanilla `cache_control :public, :max_age => 3600` statements with no luck.

I have managed to set `public, max-age=3600` on the articles themselves (e.g. `/2012/lazy-sundays/`), but have not been able to get the headers to apply to the CSS/JS (e.g. `/stylesheets/screen.css`)

My `config.ru` currently looks like this (**updated**):

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra/base'

# The project root directory
$root = ::File.dirname(__FILE__)

class SinatraStaticServer < Sinatra::Base

  get(/.+/) do
    cache_control :public, :max_age => 7200
    send_sinatra_file(request.path) {404}
  end

  not_found do
    send_sinatra_file('404.html') {"Sorry, I cannot find #{request.path}"}
    cache_control :no_cache, :max_age => 0
  end

  def send_sinatra_file(path, &missing_file_block)
    file_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'public',  path)
    file_path = File.join(file_path, 'index.html') unless file_path =~ /\.[a-z]+$/i  
    File.exist?(file_path) ? send_file(file_path) : missing_file_block.call
  end

end

use Rack::Deflater

run SinatraStaticServer
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how to set long expiry headers for static assets, and an arbitrary expiry header for you main content on Heroku:

gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-contrib'
```

config.ru:

```
require 'rack/contrib'

get '*.html' do |page|
  # whatever code you need to serve up your main pages
  # goes here... use Rack::File I guess.
  page
end


# Set content headers for that content...
before do
  expires 5001, :public, :must_revalidate
end


# Assets in /static/stylesheets (domain.com/stylesheets) 
# are served by Rack StaticCache, with a default 2 year expiry.

use Rack::StaticCache, :urls => ["/stylesheets"], :root => Dir.pwd + '/static'

run Sinatra::Application
```

By default that will give you a 2 year expiry for content listed in the array of urls (static/stylesheets, static/images etc.).

You have to move from /public to /static because otherwise you are unnecessarily fighting with Heroku's nginx config (the right place to apply these sorts of settings really...).

I know you said you're trying to not use Rack Contrib but that makes no sense. There's no harm in using a tiny 90 line library to do this https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib/blob/master/lib/rack/contrib/static_cache.rb.

The "right" way would be to host static content on an environment where you can configure nginx, and the second best way is renaming your static file path so heroku ignores it, and use rack static to serve static files with the headers you want.

--

Also to be clear, simply renaming your public folder to something else will allow you to do this via routes, and the normal Sinatra expires function. But I'd use StaticCache because it's less verbose. (The real issue is Heroku doesn't let nginx talk to your app for requests to public/, I believe.)

Comment: I was trying to "avoid" using it so that I wouldn't have to start patching Octopress. Its default rake tasks use SASS to put CSS files in /public/stylesheets, and posts in /public as well. It's not really a big deal to modify the rake script (mind you), but it might make future merges with new release more headache inducing. But I digress.

Your solution looks like the best fit—I have half of it working already (main pages are already served with the right cache headers)—so I just need to change references from /public to /static and go from there to avoid Heroku's default behaviour.

Comment: Also: How do I override the 2 year duration for `StaticCache`? I want to avoid versioning my CSS as I have to re-generate the whole site each time I make a CSS change—but I'd like to be able to have a clients cache it for a week (604800s) as I don't plan on making major changes. Can I just create a new `duration_in_seconds` function within my Rack::StaticCache class and specify `60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * @cache_duration`?

Comment: Pass in a :duration => 1 value. It only works in years by default though. (so that's a 1 year expiry). You could make it do other arbitrary values by replacing the duration_in_seconds method with one that just returns the value you passed in. And so then it could be seconds.

Comment: I'd suggest timestamping your css though. Assuming octopress will let you add something like `"?#{Time.now.to_i}"` after your css files, then you don't have to guess your expiry times, can set them as far out as possible, and people will never get stale assets.

Answer (score 1):

I have very little familiarity with Sinatra, but I *think* something like this would do the trick:

```
class SinatraStaticServer < Sinatra::Base
  before '*.html' do
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=3600'
  end

  before %r{\.(css)|(js)|(png)|(ico)} do
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=604800'
  end

  # ...
end
```

**Update:** I looked into it further when you said that the above was not successfully getting the headers added.  I determined that the issue was that Sinatra was automatically serving the files out of `public/` rather than going through the app, and thus the headers weren't being added.  My solution was to move the static files from `public/` to `public/public/` and adjust `send_sinatra_file` accordingly:

```
class SinatraStaticServer < Sinatra::Base
  # ...

  def send_sinatra_file(path, &missing_file_block)
    file_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'public/public',  path)
    file_path = File.join(file_path, 'index.html') unless file_path =~ /\.[a-z]+$/i
    File.exist?(file_path) ? send_file(file_path) : missing_file_block.call
  end

  # ...
end
```

I confirmed that this works on my machine.  Note that I used `response.headers['Cache-Control']` as in the first part of my answer, not `set :static_cache_control` which you tried, but I think is meant to only be run once, in a `configure do` block.

Also note that with this current set-up, a 404 that matches the above, e.g. `nonexistant.png` will serve a 404 status with the Cache-Control header still there.  I can see several ways around that, but I figure you do to, so I'm just pointing it out and figure you'll deal with it however you like.

Comment: Thanks - feels halfway there but still not passing the headers (checking via curl and askapache.com)

I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904462/rackresponseheaders-in-rackup-for-sinatra but trying to avoid using rack-contrib as it feels like it's not the "best" (short) way to do it.

I also dug into http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Cache%20Control and used `set :static_cache_control , [:public, :max_age => 3600]` within `before ... do` blocks but it's still not adding the Cache-Control headers.

Comment: PS: I have added information on my specific attempts to the original question, if that helps you help me solve this. Thanks for your response so far - has helped me narrow down what I need to do.

Comment: @elithrar Since I'm too tired to work on any of my own projects today, I had time to kill. I installed Sinatra, played around with this, and have figured out why the headers weren't being added.  See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to avoid that though, as it is a bit of a hack (I'll also have to hack Octopress to get it to work properly, too). Looking at the Sinatra docs, the public/ folder shouldn't interfere with this, and the set :static_cache_control statement exists to handle files in public/

Comment: @elithrar Well, yeah, if you're okay having the same Cache-Control for all static files, that makes things dead-simple. Manually serving the static files yourself in order to give a custom header based on file extension is a hack, but I thought that's what you were going for. I don't think there's a built-in easy way to do it.

Comment: That's what I've feared. I've actually managed to half-solve this: anything served up under my regular URL structure gets an appropriate Cache-Control header (e.g. `/2012/say-anything/`), but not stuff in /stylesheets (et. al). I'm looking at using Rack::Static to handle this part but am running up against a wall in order to get the config.ru looking right.